# Assign to Desktop x option missing

Tags: macos, desktop, mission-control

I've noticed that my Mac no longer opens applications I've specified on my second screen. When trying to set the option again via right clicking on the icon and going to Options, the "Assign to Desktop x" is no longer displayed.

What could be the cause of this? There is definitely two screens attached to my Mac as they both display different desktops.

(I am using Mavericks)

Answer (score 1):

Following [this discussion on Apple.com](https://discussions.apple.com/message/23717442#23717442) :

You'll have to delete the following preference files :

- `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.spaces.plist` (if you have multiple `space.plist` delete each of them.
- `~/Library/Preferences/dock.plist`

Comment: I've deleted both but the option still does not exist

Comment: Same problem here. Have deleted both files. But option not available in any of the apps in the dock. Running Maverick.